# Vim shortcut in Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, vim, terminal

In vim I have `jj` bound to go to normal mode:

```
inoremap jj <ESC>
```

I changed Terminal to vi mode in ~/.bash_profile, but how can I set up the same binding? This doesn't work unfortunately:

```
bind '"jj": vi-cmd-mode'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash` the command is "vi-movement-mode":

```
bind '"jj": vi-movement-mode'
```